# Format String to Date for Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I would like to convert it to a date so that I can display it in the proper format which is, well, a ridiculous format anyways.

this is my current format (which is a string):

```
2012/03/06 00:00:00
```

this is what I'm going to change it to:

```
06-MAR-12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it.. just for reference.. had to account for  blanks, also had to format properly..

```
if isnull({Command.EXAM_DT}) then Date(0,0,0)

else

if ({Command.EXAM_DT}='') THEN Date(0,0,0) 

ELSE 

Date(ToNumber(LEFT({Command.EXAM_DT}, 4)),
      ToNumber(Mid ({Command.EXAM_DT}, 6, 2)),
      ToNumber(Mid ({Command.EXAM_DT}, 9, 2))
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

since your string is in a format Crystal will recognize create a formula

```
date({yourstringfield})
```

then right click the field to format the output it like you want

Comment: that's what I thought too.. but I get a "bad date format string"